# How to get particular name in folder name

Tags: batch-file

A directory named such as CD_25467, JBMA_33455, CCD_2133, etc, I want to store the character and numbers in two different variables. For example,

CD_25467

```
   @echo off
   set folder=D:\karthick\CD_25467
   set j=[(A-Z)+]
   set a=[(0-9)+]
   echo %j%
   echo %a%
```

The output will come,

```
CD
25467
```

How to write regex coding for the above example?

Comment: `cmd` has no REGEX support. Is it sufficient to split by `_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("D:\karthick\CD_25467") do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%A in ("%%~nI") do set "j=%%A" & set "a=%%B"
echo %j%
echo %a%
```

Open a command prompt window and run `for /?` for help on command **FOR** explaining what `%~nI` means which references name of file or folder, i.e. the string between last backslash and last dot if there is such a string at all. A folder path ending with a backslash would result in running the inner **FOR** with just `""` resulting in `j` and `a` still not defined or keeping their current string values.

The help explains also the syntax on usage of option `/F` to split one or more lines read from a text file or a single string as done here or captured lines output by a command line executed in background with `cmd.exe /C`.